# Convert CSS3 to older CSS for Browser Compatibility

Tags: css

Is there any converters (similar to Babel convert ES6 to older ES versions) that can convert CSS3 (e.g. grid, attribute selectors) to older versions of CSS so that development efficiency won't be sacrificed to trade for browser compatibility?

Comment: look up the pollyfills for what you need.

Answer (score 1):

No, because that would require a tool to understand your design intent and then fix it. If it was so easy to create cross browser compatible css by just using a magic tool we would all be using it. Usually I see this done the other way around. Get it to work in all browsers and then hack in fixes for older browsers.

Comment: I guess so, perhaps it's not as easy compared to Javascript, where there are older equivalent features (e.g. arrow function) that could more easily be converted.